# adf mobile - textinput - to prevent entering or disabling the emoticons in iphone

Tags: mobile, oracle-adf-mobile

How do I prevent users entering emoticons in a textinput field please? I mean disabling the emoticons in iphone during text input.

Comment: can someone look into this please?

Comment: In the iphone adf mobile app, how do I prevent users entering an image in a textinput field please
(I mean disabling the emoticons in iphone during text input)